# Django how to import value in request function from another one?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have the following structure:

- app1
- app2

In the app1 I have a view named `stato_patrimoniale`:

```
def stato_patrimoniale(request):
    now=datetime.datetime.now()
    last_account_year=float(now.year)-1 #definizione dell'ultimo anno contabile
    now = now.year
    if request.method == 'POST':
        year = request.POST['year']
        if year != '':
            now = year
            last_account_year = float(now) - 1
    context= {
         'last_account_year': last_account_year}

    return render(request, 'stato_patrimoniale/stato_patrimoniale.html', context)
```

in the app2 I have a function named my_func()

Now I want to use the `last_account_year` value in the my_func() in the app 2 in which I have the following function:

```
def my_func():
    last_account_year = ""
```

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is set a global for the value of `last_account_year`

For example:

```
last_account_year_global = o

def stato_patrimoniale(request):
    // your view
    global last_account_year_global
    last_account_year_global = last_account_year

def view2(request):
    print last_account_year_global
```

if you need it in another app, you can store it in a session. make sure to add `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'` to your MIDDLEWARE

for example:

```
def stato_patrimoniale(request):
    // your view
    request.session['last_account_year'] = last_account_year

def view2(request):
    try:
       last_account_year = request.session['last_account_year']
    except KeyError:
       // last_account_year not in session
       pass
```

Comment: Thanks but if the views is in another app?

Comment: @FedericoDeMarco I updated my answer for your case. Let me know if it works.

Comment: give me the following error  `name 'request' is not defined`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. The second view in realty is a function. So I update my answer

Comment: the second view is not a view(reuqest) but a simple function my_func(). Sorry for my fault

Comment: In other words is it possible to import a value in a view(request) in another function() in another app?

Comment: @FedericoDeMarco and where do you use this function? in another view? you could then pass request to this function

Comment: This is a function in the view. How could import it?

Comment: @FedericoDeMarco Show the view where you would use that function

Comment: @FedericoDeMarco Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216133/discussion-between-vincent-and-federico-de-marco).